# Start Action Mode from custom CursorAdapter within ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment, android-cursoradapter, contextual-action-bar, android-actionmode

I am trying to start action mode for a contextual action bar, but I'm having issues. I am using a custom CursorAdapter for a class that extends ListFragment that is contained by a class that extends ActionBarActivity.

Structure
GameListActivity (ActionBarActivity)
---- GameListFragment (ListFragment)
---- ---- custom_adapter (CursorAdapter)

I'm trying to start the action mode in an onClick listener within the custom_adapter. Currently, I have the ActionMode.Callback in the ActionBarActivity:

```
public static final ActionMode.Callback AnActionMode = new ActionMode.Callback() {
    // standard funcs (onCreateActionMode, etc)
}
```

I feel as though this would be better suited in the ListFragment, but I've tried that with no better luck.

In my custom CursorAdapter, I have a function:

```
private void set_action_mode() {
    if (checked_count > 0)
        if (!is_action_mode_showing)
            ((GameListActivity) m_context).startActionMode(GameListActivity.AnActionMode);
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Error:(142, 47) error: method startActionMode in class Activity cannot be applied to given types;
required: android.view.ActionMode.Callback
found: android.support.v7.view.ActionMode.Callback
reason: actual argument android.support.v7.view.ActionMode.Callback cannot be converted to android.view.ActionMode.Callback by method invocation conversion
```

Both classes import (what I think) is the proper class:

```
import android.support.v7.view.ActionMode;
```

I was original following [this](http://techiedreams.com/gmail-like-flip-animated-multi-selection-list-view-with-action-mode/) link, but his implementation doesn't appear to work for me either.

Is there anyway to do what I'm doing?

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use

> startSupportActionMode

instead of

> startActionMode

Hope its helpful!

PS: Take a look of your sintaxis. Java convention says that the name of all variables, objects or methods must start with lowercase and no underscores are allowed. It seems that you're using the style of the C naming. You can find more info at [oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)
and [here](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm).